# FirebaseException: Failed to parse node with class in NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON

Tags: java, firebase

I'm using Firebase in Java. The following simple code has always worked fine when users' information had to be updated:

```
final FirebaseBean_User userObject = new FirebaseBean_User(uuid, name, timestamp, points, gamesPlayed, gamesWon);
mFirebaseUser.setValue(userObject, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

I used the current timestamp as the priority value so that I can get a list of all users that have been online recently.

However, when users go offline, I would like to mark them as offline. Thus, I added one simple line again in the middle:

```
final FirebaseBean_User userObject = new FirebaseBean_User(uuid, name, timestamp, points, gamesPlayed, gamesWon);
mFirebaseUser.onDisconnect().setValue(userObject, USER_PRIORITY_OFFLINE); // best practice: always call onDisconnect() before the actual setValue() operation to prevent ghost data
mFirebaseUser.setValue(userObject, System.currentTimeMillis());
```

And suddenly this piece of code stopped working. I'm getting the following Exception, where the causing line (465) is the new one in the middle:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse node with class class com.my.package.MultiplayerService$FirebaseBean_User
    at com.firebase.client.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(NodeUtilities.java:130)
    at com.firebase.client.OnDisconnect.setValue(OnDisconnect.java:81)
    at com.my.package.MultiplayerService.updateUserInformation(MultiplayerService.java:465)
    at com.my.package.MultiplayerService.access$4(MultiplayerService.java:461)
    at com.my.package.MultiplayerService$1.onDataChange(MultiplayerService.java:83)
    at com.firebase.client.core.ValueListenerContainer$1.run(ValueListenerContainer.java:50)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Why does that happen? Am I doing anything wrong? I mean, `setValue()` worked fine before, now the only change is that I call it on `onDisconnect()` as well and it stops working.

(It does not matter if there has been data at that reference point before or not.)

Here is the class that is used for reference:

```
private static class FirebaseBean_User {

    private String uuid;
    private String name;
    private int lastlogin;
    private double points;
    private int gamesplayed;
    private int gameswon;

    private FirebaseBean_User() { }

    public FirebaseBean_User(String uuid, String name, int lastlogin, double points, int gamesplayed, int gameswon) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastlogin = lastlogin;
        this.points = points;
        this.gamesplayed = gamesplayed;
        this.gameswon = gameswon;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getLastlogin() {
        return lastlogin;
    }

    public double getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public int getGamesplayed() {
        return gamesplayed;
    }

    public int getGameswon() {
        return gameswon;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return (o instanceof FirebaseBean_User && ((FirebaseBean_User) o).getUuid() == this.uuid);
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that onDisconnect can't parse the object FirebaseBean_User (userObject) into or from a JSON string.

Comment: Yes, this is obvious by the `Exception` that is thrown (_into_ JSON), but the question is _why_ exactly this is so. As you can see, `onDisconnect().setValue()` and `setValue()` are writing the same object to the reference node, but with `setValue()` it works, and with `onDisconnect().setValue()` (only 1 line before), it does not work. Why?

Comment: What is the value of USER_PRIORITY_OFFLINE? I'm guessing the engine isn't able to parse that into valid JSON.

Comment: @Anant: It's an integer constant with value `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, what could be wrong with that?

Comment: Yes, that seems fine and should work. I'll ask our dev team to look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is in fact a bug in the Firebase SDK, sorry about that! Specifically, it's an issue in the OnDisconnect handler. That's why it works for ref.setValue, but not ref.onDisconnect().setValue. I'll get a fix together ASAP and update my answer once it's available.

Edit: try grabbing the latest SDK from https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html
It should be version 1.0.4. Let me know if you continue to have trouble.

Comment: Still facing the same problem, Exception is: `com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to parse node with class class MY_CLASS_NAME`, I am trying to save as: `ref.child("users").child(encodeEmail(mEmail)).setValue(encodeEmail(mEmail), user);`, please note that i am doing this first time after creating the project on Firebase.

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal I'm facing the same issue with setValue(.. , ..) method. Could you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a JSON parsing trouble, at the com.firebase.client.snapshot.NodeUtilities class.

I haven't found any doc on this class, but from my experience with other serialization/parsing engines, I suspect the problem lies on your `FirebaseBean_User` class, due to the lack of an empty accesible (as in public) constructor.

Most of the parsing engines end up making a call to the `Class<?>.newInstance()` method, wich instantiates the object invoking the empty constructor.

So, try changing:

```
private FirebaseBean_User() { }
```

for:

```
public FirebaseBean_User() { }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not change _anything_. I've now made the class `FirebaseBean_User` a separate class (not nested anymore) and made all constructors, methods and fields public - no change. Furthermore, the private default constructor was exactly the way Firebase suggests to do it, see the first code example (Java) here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html

Comment: OK. Sorry not having helped.

Comment: No problem :) Your suggestion seemed perfectly reasonable, and because nothing seems to work, I guess its a bug in the Firebase SDK.